# Magento 2 Invoice PDF logo looks blurred

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf, zend-framework, logo

I have uploaded Invoice logo with size 200X50 as recommended. However when the invoice is downloaded the image looks blurred and takes the dimensions about 309X79. Any idea why is it taking this size? Where Can I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working! `drawImage` function uses **points** instead of **pixels**. Changed code in `insertLogo` function to convert pixels in points.

```
$width = $image->getPixelWidth()* 72 / 96;
$height = $image->getPixelHeight()* 72 / 96;
```